# Facebook Page Like Button: How to know if the user has Liked or not after switching back from Safari

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-like, xcode7, facebook-ios-sdk

Once a user has Liked or not and the app is switched back from safari, I want to perform some actions if the user has "Liked".

How can i do this?

I am using ios-fbsdk 4.6, xcode 7, ios9.

I also tried looking into the FBSDK but found nothing. I know its possible and have seen it applied into some of the apps but couldn't find any clue from where to begin. Any thoughts? Thx